# Deleting duplicates in Impala via Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, impala

iam trying to delete duplicate values by partition (dt), but iam getting error:

```
An error was encountered:
u'Cannot overwrite a path that is also being read from.;'
```

Query i'am using is:

```
query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM {} WHERE dt = '{}'".format(table_name, partition_date)
df = spark.sql(query)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_table")
overwrite_query = "INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE {} PARTITION (dt) SELECT * FROM temp_table".format(table_name, partition_date)
```

Where iam I wrong ?

Comment: have you saved your data before overwriting?

Comment: Yes, its backup copy

Comment: Basically, you are writing in the same path where you are reading from. And that's not possible.  On this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76959833/change-column-name-in-table-and-delta-files/76960618#76960618) you can see how to get around it and write where you are reading from.